# Minitest: how to stub with a mock, and verify its arguments

Tags: ruby, mocking, arguments, minitest, stubbing

Here is a tiny example regarding mocking a class method of `module Email`. The method is called `connect_and_send`:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
module Email
  def self.connect_and_send(*args)
    nil
  end
end
class Test < Minitest::Test
  def test_it
    fake = Minitest::Mock.new
    fake.expect :connect_and_send, nil, ['a', 'b', 'c']
    Email.stub :connect_and_send, fake do
      Email.connect_and_send 'a', 'b', 'z'
    end
    fake.verify
  end
end
```

The example is intended to verify that the method is invoked, along with its arguments.

But it produces an error message that `connect_and_send` was expected, but not invoked!

```
  1) Error:
Test#test_it:
MockExpectationError: expected connect_and_send("a", "b", "c") => nil
    -:14:in 'test_it'

1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Instead, I thought it would produce an error message that the method (`connect_and_send`) was given incorrect arguments.

Using Minitest, how can I stub with a mock, and also verify its arguments?

Answer (score 9):

The answer is to `expect` method, `:call`, instead of `expect`ing method, `connect_and_send`. The following code:

```ruby
require 'minitest/autorun'
module Email
  def self.connect_and_send(*args)
    nil
  end
end
class Test < Minitest::Test
  def test_it
    fake = Minitest::Mock.new
    fake.expect :call, nil, ['a', 'b', 'c']
    Email.stub :connect_and_send, fake do
      Email.connect_and_send 'a', 'b', 'z'
    end
    fake.verify
  end
end
```

verifies, in the desired way, which arguments were passed to the method, `connect_and_send`.

It gives the proper error message, that the stubbed method was passed the incorrect arguments:

```
  1) Error:
Test#test_it:
MockExpectationError: mocked method :call called with unexpected arguments ["a", "b", "z"]
    -:12:in 'block in test_it'
    -:11:in 'test_it'

1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

And it proves that the code under test invoked the method, `connect_and_send`.

If an object has multiple methods you wish to stub—while verifying their arguments—then use more than one mock.

Here's Minitest's documentation of `Object#stub`. Technically it's correct, when it [says](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/minitest/5.11.2/Object) of its second parameter (see the third line):

> > **#stub**(name, val_or_callable, *block_args) ⇒ Object
>
> Add a temporary stubbed method replacing **name** for the duration of the **block**.
> If **val_or_callable** responds to #call, then it returns the result of calling it[.]

Yet, I suppose that many people (as did I) will misread the documentation in this phrase as meaning, instead, a "call" to the stubbed method, such as—in this example—the `connect_and_send` method. Why? Because:

1. In the third line, the word, 'call' has two meanings; and
2. The hash character `#` in `#call` slightly resembles each of the letters E, H, and T, which are all that's required, in order to misread `#call` as:

> If **val_or_callable** responds to the call, then it returns the result of calling it[.]

Anyway, the documentation IMO would be improved by adding the word, "method":

> If **val_or_callable** has a #call method, then it returns the result of invoking it[.]

To me, the examples in the Minitest documentation (in [Object#stub](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/minitest/5.11.2/Object) and [Mock](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/minitest/5.11.2/Minitest/Mock)) perhaps seem somewhat incomplete, when mocking and stubbing are combined.

Again, when you verify arguments passed to your mock (using Minitest), you should `expect` method `:call`, instead of `expect`ing the method you're stubbing!

Comment: Is there way to see the diff between the expected and the received args?